# Eclipse JVM exit code 13 under Solaris Sparc

Tags: eclipse, jvm, solaris

I downloaded this eclipse archive: eclipse-SDK-4.4.1-solaris-gtk.zip

I changed the eclipse.ini to point to the JVM.

But Eclipse can't launch:

```
-bash-4.1$ ./eclipse
Eclipse:
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/export/home/bob/jdk/jre/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /tmp/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os solaris
-ws gtk
-arch sparc
-showsplash /tmp/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0.v20140925-0400/splash.bmp
-launcher /tmp/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /tmp/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.solaris.sparc_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so
-startup /tmp/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 3
-vm /export/home/bob/jdk/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /tmp/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

The arch of the machine:

```
-bash-4.1$ uname -a
SunOS s1A 5.11 11.1 sun4v sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5220
```

Java looks happy:

```
-bash-4.1$ /export/home/bob/jdk/jre/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)
```

Any idea?

---

For future reference:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=429343
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=442266

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://www.eclipse.org/projects/project-plan.php?planurl=eclipse/development/plans/eclipse_project_plan_4_4.xml#target_environments , it's a 32-bit build. You'll need a 32-bit JRE.